# RabbitMQ .NET Client Not Working with TLS v1.2

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, rabbitmq

Trying to get RabbitMQ wired up to play nice with TLS v1.2. Working with both a Java client and a .NET Core client. The Java client is working but the .NET one is pushing back. Here are my factory settings:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
   HostName = hostName,
   VirtualHost = vHost,
   UserName = username,
   Password = password,
   Port = 5671,
   Ssl = {Enabled = true}
};
```

I’m getting this exception: 
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. 
---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL. 
---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Looking at the very tail end of the exception message it appears that the TLS version might be old but I have the latest version of RabbitMQ installed – 4.1.1

Dug into the RabbitMQ source for the ConnectionFactory class but cannot find anything relating to setting the TLS version. In my Java app it works thusly: factory.useSslProtocol("TLSv1.2");

Saw in another SO thread that an old version of Erlang might be the cause but I have the latest version (8.1) installed.

Any pointers on where to look next?

UPDATE: Foound the way to set the TLS property: 
factory.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;

But now I'm getting a System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid exception.

Comment: Can you share your configuration file?    Also, do you have the certificate for the Certificate Authority in the Trusted Root Certification folder of CertMgr

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

```
Ssl = new SslOption
{
    Version = SslProtocols.Tls12,
    Enabled = true,
}
```